# ignoring mis-configured plug-in at /Path/To/Foo.appex: plug-ins must be sandboxed

Tags: sandbox, code-signing, codesign, entitlements, macos-app-extension

I'm getting this message spammed in the console:

[image: The error line repeated many many times in Console.app]

Additionally, my extension doesn't show up in System Preferences:
[image: The System Preferences' Extensions pane, showing my extension wasn't installed]
<sup>(no, I'm not developing OneNote)</sup>

---

Here are the commands I use to install the extension, each of which claims it succeeded:

[image: The terminal view of installing the extension]

And here is proof that the extension is indeed sandboxed:

[image: The Xcode project, showing the AppEx and its sandboxed nature]

---

The only possible problem I can imagine involves our code signing process. For various reasons, it's codesigned **after** it's compiled, using a command like the following:

```bash
codesign --force --entitlements "$ENTITLEMENT" --sign "$CODESIGN_ID" --deep "$APPEX_PATH"
```

This is a requirement and, sadly, cannot be bypassed. Codesigning must be done *after* the `appex` artifact is generated.

However, this has not been a problem in the past. This is the say it's been done for a while and it worked fine. The only difference I can think of is that now we are bundling in two new `.framework`s... but those are signed as well, so I'm not sure what to do.

When I remove the frameworks from the project and move codesigning to Xcode, it works... but that's not a permanent solution since we still need to manually codesign later on in our process.

**What can I do to get this extension installed *and* preserve our codesigning requirement?**

Comment: Have you check removing those 2 new framework and see if it works? Also possible you made an XCode upgrade recently?

Comment: Yes, I have tried removing the frameworks and it still fails just the same way

Comment: Well, @TarunLalwani, when I delete them from the artifact it fails the same way. When I remove them from the appex completely and shuffle signing from `codesign` to Xcode's built-in code signing, things seem to work... but that's not a permanent solution because of how we handle the final signing process

Comment: Any help on this would be great !!! Facing the exact same issue